# using one_of/vars inside of a function in mutate_all

Tags: r, dplyr

I need to subtract all columns of a data set by one of the columns.  The name of the column I need is dynamic, stored outside of the data set, and represented as `c("a")` below.

```
dataset <- data.frame(a = c(0.021, 0.011, -0.031, -0.021, -0.041, 0.061), 
                      b = c(0.022, 0.012, -0.032, -0.022, -0.042, 0.062), 
                      c = c(0.010, 0.000, -0.020, 0.010, -0.030, 0.070))
dataset %>% mutate_all(funs( (. - one_of(c("a"))) ))
```

When I run this the resulting error is `Evaluation error: Variable context not set.` I know this must be related to calling `one_of()` inside of `funs()`. A slightly less elegant solution is:

```
dataset - dataset %>% select(one_of("a")) %>% pull
```

Nevertheless, I'm curious why I can't do the former.

Comment: You could also try this `dataset %>%
  mutate_at(vars(-one_of(c("a"))), funs(new = . - a))`

Comment: Thanks Miha, but "a" will change, so I can't refer to it directly in the code.  Thus `funs(new = . - a)` will get me in trouble.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to dynamically choose the column to subtract, you'll need to use [tidyeval](https://edwinth.github.io/blog/dplyr-recipes/).

One way to write such a function: First create a quosure of your subtraction column with `enquo`, then use this to select the column to subtract inside `mutate_all`. The bit `.[[quo_name(col_quo)]]` is the tidyeval equivalent to `.$a`, which you might have used if you were using a set column.

```r
library(dplyr)

dataset <- data.frame(a = c(0.021, 0.011, -0.031, -0.021, -0.041, 0.061), 
                      b = c(0.022, 0.012, -0.032, -0.022, -0.042, 0.062), 
                      c = c(0.010, 0.000, -0.020, 0.010, -0.030, 0.070))

subtract_col <- function(data, col) {
  col_quo <- enquo(col)

  data %>%
    mutate_all(function(x) x - .[[quo_name(col_quo)]])
}

subtract_col(dataset, a)
#>   a      b      c
#> 1 0  0.001 -0.011
#> 2 0  0.001 -0.011
#> 3 0 -0.001  0.011
#> 4 0 -0.001  0.031
#> 5 0 -0.001  0.011
#> 6 0  0.001  0.009

subtract_col(dataset, c)
#>        a      b c
#> 1  0.011  0.012 0
#> 2  0.011  0.012 0
#> 3 -0.011 -0.012 0
#> 4 -0.031 -0.032 0
#> 5 -0.011 -0.012 0
#> 6 -0.009 -0.008 0
```

Created on 2018-07-31 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

Comment: Thank you, very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You could do this:

```
dataset %>% mutate_all(`-`,.$a)
#   a      b      c
# 1 0  0.001 -0.011
# 2 0  0.001 -0.011
# 3 0 -0.001  0.011
# 4 0 -0.001  0.031
# 5 0 -0.001  0.011
# 6 0  0.001  0.009
```

Or similar to @Miha's comment:

```
dataset %>% transmute_all( funs(new=. - a))
#   a_new  b_new  c_new
# 1     0  0.001 -0.011
# 2     0  0.001 -0.011
# 3     0 -0.001  0.011
# 4     0 -0.001  0.031
# 5     0 -0.001  0.011
# 6     0  0.001  0.009
```

I we skip the `new=`, a is first subtracted from itself and can't be used for the other variables (thanks @aosmith).

Comment: It's because `a` is the first variable subtracted from itself and so this mutated version (which is all 0) replaces the original `a` for the rest of the variables.

Comment: Thanks Moody, but my problem is that I can't refer to 'a' in the code since it will change.  In fact, maybe it would be clearer if I changed `c("a")` to `mySelection <- c("a")`.

Answer (score 0):

Camille's answer had all the pieces to get there, however, if you are looking for a one-liner down the road:

```
dataset %>% mutate_all(funs((. - !!rlang::sym(c("a")))))
```